# Wordpress Editor completely blank

Tags: plugins, block-editor

Although the classic editor works, I am unable to use Gutenberg. When I disable plugins in wp-content (by changing plugins to pluginsOLD), I can edit everything just fine.

How can I restore the new editor's functionality?

Comment: Disable all your plugins. Turn them on one at a time, checking the editor after each one. When the editor goes blank, you've found the problematic plugin. You'll need to deactivate it, or contact its maintainer for further assistance.

Comment: well, you know it's a plugin problem, so now find which is the plugin that is doing it but deactivating each plugin one by one and checking to find the one, then replace the plugin.

Comment: @Castiblanco I'll accept this as an answer. I just needed to know what to do once I found the faulty plugin.

Comment: Leave the plugin disabled or contact the author to see if they have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know it's a plugin problem, so now it's time to find which is the plugin that is doing it but deactivating each plugin one by one and checking to find the one, once you find the faulty plugin you will have to:

- Replace it with a similar one
- Trying to debug it to find it's problem

But to be honest, normally it's better to use another plugin that does the same or code the functionality of the faulty plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the completely blank Gutenberg issue. Once you find the offending plugin and/or theme, in case it helps you trace the offending lines of code (e.g. in case you want to fix or re-implement that functionality), I'll share what I recall:

- in one case the script enqueues were being adjusted by a plugin to use a different jQuery, modernizr, etc version and whatever combination it was going for borked things
- in another case I had an overzealous regex in a filter whose purpose was to clean up the `type="text/javascript"` from `<link>` tags (to pass the W3C HTML5 validator without warnings). Other JS was running fine but Gutenberg blanked out the way you describe.

Both cases were related to messing around with WordPress' defaults as related to JavaScript.

In tracing an offender, be sure to have your browser's developer tools open, e.g. Chrome -> Right click + inspect. Check the Console for errors or messages that might give you better insight.